# Will Rebol 3 support SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: rebol

I asked the question "Will Rebol 3 extension support any windows api call including those requiring callback ?".

Now to be sure and to take an example, will it possible to use Win 32 SetWindowsHookEx() and do screen capture like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Screen_Capture__Win32_.aspx

Rebol is really missing screen capture function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carl has released a new hostkit that support callbacks.

see http://www.rebol.net/r3blogs/0329.html

Answer (score 0):

I've actually built a screen capture and Image editing application in REBOL for Qtask, so yes, its already possible in R2.  :-)

https://www.qtask.com/qwiki.cgi?mode=previewSynd&uuid=RX1BV28XG68G87ERFEA2BXLQ63QT

Comment: Yes I tried it is really great. But how the windows look native? They don't look like VID windows? Did you use something else? Or is it custom completely?

Comment: its all an advanced VID skin, and the canvas uses my dataflow graphics engine, which is a node graph scene manager.

Comment: oh you mean GLASS and LIQUID, ok now I got it :)

Comment: actually, it's pure VID (no Glayout) with some Liquid built into it.  this tool is already 3 years old and it predates GLASS by two!